# How can I set text for an ENUM and support multi language?

Tags: android, string, enums

I have an `enum` class for two types of math values, which are, `AMOUNT` and `PERCENTAGE`.

These two are radio buttons and depending on what radio button the user selects. The text is set accordingly.

Till now, my app is has only one language but now I have made it multi-lingual. How can I set the text of `ENUM` depending on the language?

This is my `enum`:

```
public enum DiscountTypeEnum {
    AMOUNT,
    PERCENTAGE;
    private DiscountTypeEnum() {
    }
}
```

I would like to set the string based on what `discountType` the user selects,

```
for (DiscountTypeEnum discountType : DiscountTypeEnum.values()) {
     RadioButton discountTypeButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
     // below is where I need to set the text from string resource file
     // setText(R.string.AMOUNT) or setText(R.string.PERCENTAGE)
     discountTypeButton.setText(discountType.name());
     discountTypes.addView(discountTypeButton);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the name of the enums directly, you can use string resources with locale qualifiers. You can store the strings for different languages in separate `strings.xml` files per locale, and then read the resources with

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

at runtime, which will give you the resource for the current language of the device, if it's available.

More info in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

```
enum FRUITS {
    APPLE(R.string.apple),
    BANANA(R.string.banana);

    private @StringRes
    int label;

    FRUITS(@StringRes int label) { this.label = label; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MyApplication.getApplicationContext().getString(label);
    }
}
```

For non android: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256806/best-approach-for-multilingual-java-enum

Comment: My ENUM is a java class and not android. In that case, how can I use multi language strings?